# Calls into WinRT from desktop application that works on Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-7, windows-runtime

I need to use some of the WinRT APIs from my desktop app. The only issue is that my app needs to work on Windows 7 as well as 8 and 10.

The WinRT APIs I want to use will augment the information that I can get from any Windows version.

By referencing `Windows.winmd` and targeting 8.0 the app will no longer run on Windows 7.

What are the possibilities to make this work?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No. May be possible now though through .NET Standard or dynamic loading of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very clear and simple: On Windows 7, No.

Mehdi

Comment: I think that is incorrect. I don't want to call into WinRT APIs from Windows 7. I want to call them **only** if I am on Windows 8/10.

Comment: You can do a conditional referencing + preprocessor directives

Comment: Using preprocessor directives I'd have to compile a separate version for Windows 7 and 8/10? That really doesn't work in my case.